# PHP reference and sharing variables

Tags: php, class, reference

I have a curl handler but will show example on standard type variable. Here are two classes and i want to share one variable from first class to second class as a reference.

```
<?php
class first
{
    private $a=10;
    private $b='cos'; 

    public function SendData()
    {
        $data = array(
            'first' => &$this->a,
            'second' => $this->b
        );

        return $data;
    }

    public function GetA() { return $this->a; }
    public function GetB() { return $this->b; }
}

class second
{
    private $a;
    private $b; 

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->a = $data['first'];
        $this->b = $data['second'];
    }

    public function GetA() { return $this->a; }
    public function GetB() { return $this->b; }
    public function Change($i) { $this->a = $i; }
}

$f = new first();
$s = new second($f->SendData());

echo $f->GetA() . " " . $f->GetB() . PHP_EOL;
echo $s->GetA() . " " . $s->GetB() . PHP_EOL;
$s->Change(123);
echo $f->GetA() . " " . $f->GetB() . PHP_EOL;
echo $s->GetA() . " " . $s->GetB() . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

and output is like:

```
10 cos 
10 cos 
10 cos 
123 cos
```

And my question is - how to do it like pointer in C, when i call second::Change($i) function i want to change also first::$a value, so output would be like:

```
10 cos 
10 cos 
123 cos 
123 cos
```

Comment: you can't, really, since first::$a is a private variable. there's nothing `second` can do to reach inside `first` to fiddle with that value. you'd need something in `first` to return that reference, which means `first` needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a function which returns by reference. You have already a function in `first` to return `$this->a`, but the function returns the value and not by reference. You can achieve that by putting a `&` before the method name `public function &GetA(` and before calling the method in your script `$a = &$first->GetA() //gets reference to $this->a in first`.

But before that you need to get an instance of your `first` class in your `second` class. Now that we mentioned that, you have three options:

1. Declare a variable which contains an instance of `first` as global
2. Pass the variable as parameter to `second::change()`
3. Make first a singleton class, which returns always the same instance

The easiest to do is option 1, though I don't recommend that if you do a lot of things. Option 3 is the best option and should be always done if possible. Option 2 is something you can easily implement if you don't have dozens of files which use the class.

If you've implemented a way to give `second` an instance of `first` you can  get the variable by reference in your `second::change()` function and change that variable to the new value.

Reference:

3v4l.org simple get by reference https://3v4l.org/i6X5L

3v4l.org class sample get by reference (with global) https://3v4l.org/iL2Qf